# How to determine amount of mother starter to use to build a levain for STIFF/dry sourdough starter?

Tags: sourdough

I have a healthy, active dry sourdough starter (50% hydration). Most of the recipes I want to use it in, ask for anywhere between 100 g, 150g and 200 g. How much of the starter would I have to use in order to prepare a levain of those quantities?

Comment: 100, 150, and 200 grams of starter?  Can you clarify?

Comment: yes, different recipes I would like to try (not for bread btw) require levain amounts of 150g, 200g even 300 g (levain prepared from stiff white starter). So my question is what amount of stiff starter do I need to use to build a levain of 150  or 200 g?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in case anyone is interested, I managed (finally) to find an answer. Apparently, you don't dilute a stiff starter but just measure the required amount from the mother starter.